# What is the best way to check for memory leaks in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm implementing a sparse matrix with linked lists and it's not fun to manually check for leaks, any thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) profiler for Unix offers a decent leak detection.

However, this is only one part of a successful approach. The other part is to prevent (i.e. minimize) explicit memory handling. Smart pointers and allocators can help a great deal in preventing memory leaks. Also, *do* use the STL classes: a leak-free linked list implementation is already provided by `std::list`.

Comment: <3 valgrind. But yes, a tool, not a complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

**On Windows:**

Compuware BoundChecker (bit costly but very nice)

Visual LeakDetector (free, google it)

**On Linux/Unix:**

Purify

Comment: Purify is available for Windows too.

Answer (score 1):

The original version of Purify on Unix was brilliant. But the Windows version produced after Rational bought it is terrible. Flakey as hell. Avoid at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Anjuta,you can use valgrind module.