# Check for memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to check for memory leaks in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396100/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-memory-leaks-in-c)

There is a way to check for memory leaks after the program ended and also a way to check if there are areas of memory allocated and not yet released?

For example:

```
int main()
{
   int *iPtr = new int;

   // Was allocated memory that is not released yet?
   return 0;
   // Memory leaks?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On linux you can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). On windows you'll have to search for allocation profiler (there's [Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) and [AQTime 7](http://smartbear.com/products/free-tools/aqtime-standard/)), use [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (msvc specific, may produce false positives) or write custom memory manager that overrides global operator new/delete and reports memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Checking that all allocated memory has been freed is only part of the battle against memory leaks.

Suppose that a program allocates a megabyte of memory during every second of the program's operation, and that all of this allocated memory is freed just before program termination. Since all allocated memory is freed eventually, this is, strictly speaking, not a leak. In practice, this has the effect of a huge leak if the program is expected to run for an extended length of time.

Suppose that the program could be rewritten so that all but a tiny, tiny fraction of that megabyte per second was freed on the fly, with those tiny dredges of remaining allocated memory once again released at program termination. Still not a leak, strictly speaking, but this program certainly is better behaved than the original version. It still does have a tiny runtime leak, so the program might still create problems if it runs for weeks.

Now suppose the program could be rewritten so it's memory consumption is forever bounded by some reasonable limit. This runtime boundedness is perhaps more important a feature than is releasing all allocated memory by termination time. Proving this run-time boundedness is hard. Testing that all allocated memory is released by the time a program terminates is a much easier task. Commercial tools tend to focus on the latter for leak checks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: You're right. I voted up for your answer as it more complete than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

For Visual C++, Visual Link Detector might be a nice option.

Answer (score -3):

As far as I know, when you work in *user space* and your process terminates, all the memory allocated by that process is freed and returned to the operating system. (it is the OS itself that is running the process, to claim the memory back to his pool ;)) 
So there is nothing to check for.
Different story if you are running some task in kernel space, but the scenarios might be different depending on the Operating System you are using, I guess

Comment: Is very important to verify that the code that you wrote not allocate memory that is not released, so there's "something" to check.

Comment: "So there is nothing to check for". Incorrect. If your your program sits in memory long enough, and it leaks memory, it'll slowly reduce system performance. For example, certain linux distribution can perform horribly when system finally hits the swap file, although your experience may wary. Memory leak checking is a way to locate such bugs early. With "nothing to check for" you can easily end up writing programs that eat up 2+ gigabytes of RAM in 5 minutes and then crash, since OS doesn't allow to allocate more.

Comment: @gliderkite Apologies, I might have misunderstood your question. A memory leak makes sense only when your program *is running*. After it terminates, there is no memory leak to check. (all memory is released)

Comment: @sergico: This has been discussed thoroughly in the past, so I'd recommend not to start this "debate" ("what is memory leak") again. Memory leak is memory you wanted to free, but didn't actually release. Regardless of OS behavior towards unused memory, objects allocated on heap might contain resources that needs to be released explicitly, because OS doesn't do cleanup. So it is necessary to check for leaks.

Comment: @SigTerm: I'll be happy to understand more on the subject so :) Can you quote some link/resource talking about the topic? Is it really possible that an OS do not get back all the process allocated memory?

Comment: @sergico: There are other resources aside from memory. Let's say you have a class that contains a temporary file that is deleted in destructor. If object won't be properly deleted, destructor won't be called, and you'll leave junk on the HDD.

Comment: @SigTerm: Agreed, but I would calll this a resource leak, not a memory leak, I thought the sample code in the question was quite clear on that :) (and I swer, I'm not trolling around) will stop the discussion here :)

Comment: @sergico: I explained my position few comments ago: "leak is memory you wanted to release but didn't actually free". It is a programming bug. Whether OS cleans up your mess or not is another story. It is a bug, and it must be fixed.