# How can I be sure that I've freed all of my allocated memory in C?

Tags: c, list, memory-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to check for memory leaks in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396100/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-memory-leaks-in-c)

I'm writing a doubly linked list in **C** and most of it is implemented and working(I only need to fix some minor logic errors in traversing and possibly freeing).

**Question:**
How can I be absolutely sure that I'm freeing all the memory that I allocate? I would also like to know if there are any techniques to optimizing my allocation. Any tips or hints on how it works or links to tutorials are appreciated as well.

I'm pretty much a beginner, so any other tips in fixing my coding techniques would be appreciated. I use **gdb** to debug and I'm running on **Archbang Linux** x86_64.

Thank you for your help.

Here are the structures of the doubly linked list:

```
typedef struct node_element{
    double data;
} element;

typedef struct node_t{
    struct node_t *prev;
    struct node_t *next; 
    struct node_element element;
} node;

typedef struct list_t{
    struct node_t *head;
    struct node_t *tail;
} list;
```

This is how I create a list:

```
list *createList(){
    list *temp = malloc(sizeof(list));

    temp->head = malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->tail = malloc(sizeof(node));

    temp->head->prev = NULL;
    temp->head->next = temp->tail;
    temp->tail->prev = temp->head;
    temp->tail->next = NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

New nodes:

```
node *newNode(element * element){
    node *current = malloc(sizeof(node));
    current->element.data = element->data;

    return current;
}
```

Removing individual nodes, not very relevant to my question, but may be useful:

```
node *removeNode(list * list, node * current){
    if (current->prev == NULL)
        list->head = current->next;
    else
        current->prev->next = current->next;

    if (current->next == NULL)
        list->tail = current->prev;
    else
        current->next->prev = current->prev;

    free(current);

    return NULL;
}
```

And now the important part, when I'm done with a list I call this function:

```
list *removeList(list * list){
    node *temp; //Revised.
    //node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));

    while (list->head != NULL){
        temp = list->head->next;
        free(list->head);
        list->head = temp;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

like so:

```
a_list = removeList(a_list);
```

Comment: You're definitely leaking in removeList(), as you malloc a new node, but then just overwrite that pointer with the 'next' value for your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amongst the multitude of features it provides, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will allow you to [check for memory leaks](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html). It does this by dynamically instrumenting the memory management functions.

You might use a command like this:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes my_prog
```

Comment: I take it that gdb has no such function? I feel a bit silly that there was such a simple answer. Thank you, Mike.

Comment: Doing so is [possible](http://www.outofcore.com/2011/06/scripted-debug-using-gdb/) but `Valgrind` is a much more convenient tool for your purpose.

Comment: Tried valgrind out, this is definitely useful and much easier. Thanks, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to free up memory you can call free() function which deallocates memory, or dealloc() function, which also frees up the memory, and you are using functions, so the pointer variables you made are limited to scope of that function which automatically get deallocated once function is terminated.

Comment: This question is not about how to free memory, but about how to make sure you actually do this freeing.